# What is the proper method of disposing deity idols which are broken?

Tags: worship, idols

Jaya Radhe! Can someone explain me about broken idols of deities? There was a broken Buddha in the apartment building I live. I read they had to be thrown into the river or lake but what karma has a person of they place the deity in front of another's house? More directly, not properly disposed?

Answer (score 5):

An idol which is broken should not be worshipped. It should be given to a flowing river or to any water body.

Quoting from [Chapter 14 of Mahanirvana Tantram](http://www.aghori.it/mahanirvana_tantra.htm#CAP.14):

> [Lord Sadashiva says] **The wise man should not worship the image of a Deva which is broken** or is holed, or which has lost a limb, or has been touched by
>   a leper, or has fallen on unholy ground (100).
>   **The image of a Deva with missing limbs, or which is broken or has holes in it, should be consigned to water.** If the image has been
>   made impure by touch, it should be consecrated, and then worshipped
>   (101). The Mahapithas and Anadi-lingas are free from all deficiencies,
>   and these should always be worshipped for the attainment of happiness
>   by each worshipper as he pleases (102).

So, such idols should ideally be immersed in rivers, lakes etc.