Unhealthy signs related to shiva lingas
I have a shiva linga at home on which I provide water everyday , but recently some insects and flies fly near the shiva linga . Is this a bad sign that the linga is actually not producing any good vibes and something negative is being attracted towards it ? Thank you.

Does insects on a shiva linga also mean bad omen ? Please say something about it as I am terrified of the situation.

Should I immerse it in the Ganga ? Or do something else to ward of the negativity?

Insects coming on Shiva Linga is normal it is not a bad omen

See this (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28954/4732) to know about when an idol or Linga needs to be discarded and what is the proper method of doing so

If you are worried about insects sitting on the Lingam and thereby polluting it then that is wrong because insects,flies are always pure even though they might have come in touch with various impure objects previously. They do not make other things impure by their touch. Only if the Shiva Lingam is deformed or broken you need to discard it in the proper manner.


Cats, flies, insects, moths, worms, and frogs, come in contact with both what is pure and what is the reverse of pure; but their
contact transmits no impurity. So Manu has said.

Verse no 30 from Parashara Smriti's Chapter 7

